# Look at each row separately in a matrix (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, while-loop

I have a matrix in Matlab(2012) with 3 columns and X number of rows, X is defined by the user, so varies each time. For this example though I will use a fixed 5x3 matrix.

So I would like to perform an iterative function on each row within the matrix, while the value in the third column is below a certain value. Then store the new values within the same matrix, so overwrite the original values.

The code below is a simplified version of the problem.

```
M=[-2 -5 -3 -2 -4]; %Vector containing random values

Vf_X=M+1; %Defining the first column of the matrix
Vf_Y=M+2; %Defining the secound column of the matrix
Vf_Z=M; %Defining the third column of the matrix

Vf=[Vf_X',Vf_Y',Vf_Z']; %Creating the matrix

while Vf(:,3)<0 
Vf=Vf+1;
end
disp(Vf)
```

The result I get is

```
 1     2     0
-2    -1    -3
 0     1    -1
 1     2     0
-1     0    -2
```

Ideally I would like to get this result instead

```
 1     2     0
 1     2     0
 1     2     0
 1     2     0
 1     2     0
```

The while will not start if any value is above zero to begin with and stops as soon as one value goes above zero.

I hope this makes sense and I have supplied enough information

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Why do you think you get this desire result (with this code), if the initial values on each column are different?

Comment: Because I would like it to add a different amount to each row, so row 1  will have 2 added to it and row 2 will have 5 added to it. Does this make sense?

Comment: @user2519890: for the simple addition in your example: why not do `inds = Vf(:,3)<0; Vf(inds,:) = bsxfun(@minus, Vf(inds,:), Vf(inds,3));`?

Comment: Yes, it make sense. But your increment is on the whole matrix Vf, you need to evaluate the condition and the increment on each row separately. Look at Rody answer

Comment: Adiel, yes that was my problem not knowing how to look at each row separately, I knew what the issue was but not the solution. Yes the solution Rody gave was just what i needed. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current problem is that you stop iterating the very moment *any* of the values in the third row break the condition. Correct me if I'm wrong, but what I think you want is to *continue* doing iterations on the *remaining* rows, until the conditions are broken by *all* third columns.

You could do that like this:

```
inds = true(size(Vf,1),1);
while any(inds)
    Vf(inds,:) = Vf(inds,:)+1;
    inds = Vf(:,3) < 0;
end
```

Of course, for the simple addition you provide, there is a better and faster way:

```
inds = Vf(:,3)<0; 
Vf(inds,:) = bsxfun(@minus, Vf(inds,:), Vf(inds,3));
```

But for general functions, the `while` above will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Rody, my actual function isn't as simple as just adding 1 so the while function is the solution I need.
Thanks again.

Comment: @user2519890: I though as much :) Glad to help.